# Creating a graph structure using igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to reproduce the following plot using `igraph` in R.

[image: graph]

I have the following code:

```
library(igraph)
edges <- c(1,2, 2,3, 6,8, 6,7, 4,5, 9,10)
g<-graph(edges, n=max(edges), directed=F)
vcount(g)

plot(g, layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,vertex.label=V(g)$number, 

edge.arrow.size=0.5)
```

[image: mygraph]

I am not sure how to create the topology of the graph and produce the exact same graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `layout=` argument to specify the positions and `V(g)$color` and `E(g)$lty` to specify the vertex color and edge line types.

```
library(igraph)

edges <- c(1,2, 2,3, 6,8, 6,7, 4,5, 9,10, 1,6, 5,10)
x <- c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5)
y <- c(5:1, 5:1)

g <- graph(edges, n=max(edges), directed = FALSE)
V(g)$color <- "yellow"
E(g)$lty <- c(rep(1, 6), 3, 3)
plot(g, layout = cbind(x, y))
```

giving

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(igraph)
edges <- c(1,2, 2,3, 6,8, 6,7, 4,5, 9,10, 1,6, 5, 10)
g<-graph(edges, n=max(edges), directed=F)
E(g)$lty <- c(rep(1, length(E(g))-2), rep(2,2))
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get the same topology as the original plot?

Comment: @Raj no unless you know some seed or generating engine etc. Even when you run the plot  you will get the different plots but all represent the same graph

Comment: yes, the thing is I want to regenerate this to a PDF after knitting. I notice that they reorder newly each time.